# Can't find the downloaded file in my phone's Internal storage

Tags: android

I have the following Info on my LogCat.

```
D/TAG: LocalFile: /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Img1494533768342.jpg
```

But I can't find the downloaded image on my Phone's Gallery.

As per the **LogCat** info, The image `Img1494533768342.jpg` should present in the `MyApp` folder.

Where can I actually find it? I'm running the app in MOTO G4 mobile, android version 7 (Nougat).

Comment: Well take a File Explorer app to go to that directory.

Comment: Can't find it even! @greenapps

Comment: Which app did you use? Can you find the directory? Or what?

Comment: I saw on my PC. Went to Phone's Internal storage. The directory was not created. @greenapps

Comment: Use an app on your Android device to begin with. And if the directory is not created then why complaining that a download to that directory fails? Search the real cause.

Comment: Gotcha! Found them in `FileManager` on my Phone in the `Apps`'s `Local` directory. Thank you!! Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can upvote it! @greenapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a File Explorer app on your device to browse to the file.